# Populate values from different Models - Mongoose/MongoDB Collections - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation, populate

I have two main Schema in my project, Store, and User.

- **User** collection as displayed in `MongoDB Compass` is the following :

  ```
  _id : ObjectId("**5e830006c4cec2586875124b**")  
  hearts : Array  
  storeID : Array  
  email : "test@test.com"  
  name : "My name is Test"  
  photo : "fa75fa97-c5d8-4e63-a9ee-38441774a26e.jpeg"  
  slugAuthor : "my-name-is-test"  
  description : "My description is Test"  
  hash : "b841b82dcffdd0d517b5010d9ff2047ab447751a4e6dd573f9d55af..."  
  salt : "2bb0f785b134af11d7ca08d4086801fd880626498fbcf106c0df9a66"  
  __v : 0
  ```
- **Store** collection as displayed in `MongoDB Compass` is the following :

  ```
  _id : ObjectId("5e830050c4cec2586875124c")  
  tags : Array  
  name : "My activity is Test"  
  description : "My description us Test"  
  participants : 1  
  duree : 1  
  date : 2220-02-22T21:02:00.000+00:00  
  author : ObjectId("**5e830006c4cec2586875124b**")  
  created : 2020-03-31T08:33:20.234+00:00  
  slug : "my-activity-is-test"  
   __v : 0
  ```

**What I need** :

When I display the user information, I also want to search every Store he has created.
 As you can see, the User id is found in the Store collection `(author: ObjectId).`

I need to display those information (User + list of stores that belongs to the User) when I hit the route http://..../store/my-name-is-test/5e830006c4cec2586875124b. In my route, I need to display as a slug the "slugAuthor" and the "author: ObjectId". (this is already managed).

**What I have already tried** (using .populate()) :

In my Store Schema :

```
author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User', 
    }
```

In my User Schema :

```
listStores: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Store'}],
```

In my controller:

```
exports.myProfil = async (req, res) => {
        const user = await User.findOne({slugAuthor: req.params.slugAuthor}).populate('listStores') 
        res.render('my-profil', {user}); 
    };
```

It gives me access to the following data :

```
{
  "hearts": [],
  "listStores": [],
  "_id": "5e830006c4cec2586875124b",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "name": "My name is Test",
  "photo": "fa75fa97-c5d8-4e63-a9ee-38441774a26e.jpeg",
  "slugAuthor": "my-name-is-test",
  "description": "My description is Test",
  "__v": 0
}
```

As you can see, "listStores" array is empty but I need it to be filled with every stores created by this user.

Would you please be kind enough to help me out here,
Many thanks

Comment: In the compass, your user just has `storeID`, not `listStores` field.

Comment: Are you explicitly `$push` ing the stores id into the `listStore` array of the user that created it? If you are then this populate should work. If you are only saving the creator on the store then you probably want `listStore` as a [virtual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#populate)

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Thanks but it is not the issue. Just a misspelling.
@als : No, I havent' used `$push`, just saving the author.  

I have tried virtual but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong : 
`userSchema.virtual('listStoresAuthor', {
    ref : 'Store',
    localField: '_id', 
    foreignField: 'author._id', 
  });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation for that. Take a look at the [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'Store',
       localField: _id, // the _id of the user
       foreignField: author,
       as: "listStores" // this might be something else
     }
```

In this case instead of find you have to use User.aggregate

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it does work perfectly :)  
Thanks so much buddy

Comment: For the record, I have also done ` const store = await Store.find({author: {  
        
        $in: req.params.slugAuthor}
});`  

It works just fine ;  
// réf : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: Sorry, I haven't quite understood your question. Do I need to click somewhere to mark my question as answered by you ? Not very familiar with stackoverflow. 

And both approaches worked for me. I implemented first your recommandation and it did work. I then came accross the second approach and it works also.  
Thanks

Comment: There should be a checkbox next to it.